# Retain selected item in navbar after page reload

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

How do you retain the selected/active navbar item so it can be reselected after a page reload?

I'm using bootstrap but I don't think that is particaulrly relevant. I believe I'm wanting to store the selected item on the click then on the page load reselect that item. But how do I do that? Most of what I have seen is based on the href argument of the item, but in some places I use ActionLink.

To complicate it I also have three navbars (a menu, sub-menu and sub-sub-menu if you like) so I want to retain the selected item in each one (and set a default item. Similarly if I select and item in the menu, it should automatically select the default (first) item in it's sub-menu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/Controller1/Index/">Menu Item 1</a>)</li>
            <li><a href="/Controller2/Index/">Menu Item 2</a>)</li>
            <li><a href="/Controller3/Index/">Menu Item 3</a>)</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

if (IsSectionDefined("SubMenu"))
{
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @RenderSection("SubMenu")
            </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>
}

if (IsSectionDefined("SubSubMenu"))
{
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @RenderSection("SubSubMenu")
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".navbar li a").click(function () {
            $(".navbar li a").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    });
</script>
```

An example of the sub menus would be:

```
@section SubMenu {
    <li><a href="/SubMenu1/">SubMenu Item 1</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/SubMenu2/">SubMenu Item 2</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/SubMenu3/">SubMenu Item 3</a>)</li>
}

@section SubSubMenu {
    <li><a href="/SubSubMenu1/">SubSubMenu Item 1</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/SubSubMenu2/">SubSubMenu Item 2</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/SubSubMenu3/">SubSubMenu Item 3</a>)</li>
}
```

Comment: Kindly restrict to HTML/CSS while asking these questions.

Comment: @Praveen How do you mean?

Comment: @PraveenKumar.. yeh, what do you mean???

Comment: Both of you, `@Html.ActionLink("SubSubMenu Item 2", "SubSubMenu2")` is not HTML and the post is not tagged with `Razor`.

Comment: easy way to do is get item name from URL and check with href of all anchor and set active on same class

Comment: @B_D Please try below given JS I have used local storage cache to store previous value check and let me know if still not working for you

Comment: Please change the class name as per your solution, I just write the code as per mine solution

Comment: @Praveen Updated to remove `@Html.ActionLink`

Comment: @B_D I have removed the downvote, but still, it is not just pure HTML and CSS. Anyway, please try adding relevant tags.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Being fairly new to HTML, CSS, Razor, etc. perhaps you can tell me what else needs changed?

Comment: @B_D Not about programming, but the way of posting. See the change for yourself.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm not entirely sure what change you made, was it adding `)`, if so that's an error on my part of forgetting to add the text of the link.

Comment: Nopes. Added the tag, [tag:razor].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code and let me know if it is also not working for you -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".navbar li a").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $('#' + id).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $('#' + id).addClass("active");
            localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", id);
        });

        var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');

        if (selectedolditem != null) {
            $('#' + selectedolditem).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $('#' + selectedolditem).addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, this works if I give an id to each `<a ...>...</a>` block. Thanks.

Comment: When I select an item on the sun-menu however, I lose the menu active item. I think this can be fixed by having a local storage per navbar though.

Comment: @B_D Happy to hear it is working for you,  yes now you can use same for sub-menu as well.